# Laravel L5 Swagger "Package Unable to render this definition"

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, swagger-php, l5-swagger, darkaonlinel5-swagger

Upgraded from Laravel 8 to 9 and I received this message on swagger docs.

"Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field".

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field.

Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match OpenAPI : 3.0.n (for example, OpenAPI : 3.0.0)."

Some suggested adding

- openapi="3.0.0"

line but where can I add? When I add in

- @OA\Info()

it still throws an error like

- Unexpected field "openapi" for @OA\Info()

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is an invalid property on `@OA\Info`.

Are you sure you do not have a second annotation with that field somewhere?

It might be interesting to try run `swagger-php` on the command line against your codebase and see what that returns. Something like

```
./bin/openapi app
```

Also, what happens if you remove `@OA\Info` altogether. I would expect an error about it missing...?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I solved problem but with very interesting way,

in generated api-docs.json file, there is -"openapi": "3.0.0"-. I removed this line, refresh swagger page, add this line again and error goes away... tf...

Comment: A bug in the bundle then, perhaps? Glad you found a fix.